# Use the Euclidean Algorithm to show the $\gcd(56,72)|40$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Use the Euclidean Algorithm to show the $\gcd(56,72)|40$
How do I go about this since $b$ is larger than $a$? Usually it is the other way around when I use the Euclidean Algorithm to find the $\gcd$ of a pair of numbers.

Comment: you didn't say what is $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(b, a)$.

Comment: @amWhy so I can divide it any way I want?

Comment: First you need to find $\gcd(56, 72)$, and then you need to show that this $\gcd$ divides 40. But yes, you can start with $72$ to find the $\gcd (56, 72)$ by using the Euclidean algorthm, if you'd like.

Comment: so the gcd(56,72)=8 and gcd(56,72)|40 correct?

Comment: Indeed, you are correct, Lil.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwuj4yzoX1o

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to divide "$a$" by "$b$" first even when $b\gt a$, then the first step of the Euclidean Algorithm gives
$$56=(0)(72)+56.$$

Then the *next* step is
$$72=(1)(56)+16,$$
and you are on your way. But of course the first step was a waste of time and paper, and it would have been better to switch the order of $56$ and $72$ immediately.